# Program always outputs 0

Tags: c++

So I am making a project that makes a function to get the nth number of a fibonacci sequence. I don't think there is any error but I'im not satisfied with the results and I can't fix it.

Errors : - When you input a number the console returns 0

```
#include <cmath>

 using namespace std;

 int input(string msg)
 {
  int number = 0;
  while(number >= 0)
  {
  cin >> number;
  return 0;
  }
  return 0;
 }

int fib(int n)
{
     if ( n == 0 ) return 0;
     if ( n == 1 ) return 1;

     return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2);
}

int main()
{

 int fibonacci = input("Input a position");

 int fibber = fib(fibonacci);

 cout << fibber;


 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Step through with a debugger.

Comment: Shouldn't your `input()` function return `number`, rather than 0?

Answer (score 3):

Your `input` function returns zero. You want to return `number`. Also the while loop should run until the number entered is greater than zero (I think that was your intentions).

```
int input(string msg)
{
    int number = 0;
    while(number <= 0)
    {
        cout <<  msg;
        cin >> number;
    }
   return number;
}
```

Comment: Also, you might want to the message to say something like "Input a position that's greater than zero: ". So the user doesn't keep trying numbers that are <=0.

Comment: Also it needs to exit if input fails (e.g. user types in words) otherwise this is an infinite loop. For example the loop could contain `if ( !cin ) return 0;`